# How to register a custom Hibernate IdentifierGenerator with the JPA EntityManager?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, entitymanager, sessionfactory

When using plain Hibernate this can be done in the following way:

```
public class MyLocalSessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

    // can also be made configurable e.g. with Springs EL...
    private Class myIdentifierGeneratorClass = MyIdentifierGeneratorClass.class;

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {

        Configuration config = getConfiguration();
        MutableIdentifierGeneratorFactory identifierGeneratorFactory = config.getIdentifierGeneratorFactory();
        identifierGeneratorFactory.register("xyz", myIdentifierGeneratorClass);

        return super.buildSessionFactory(sfb);
    }
}
```

Now it's possible to write e.g.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generatorName")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generatorName", strategy = "xyz")
    private Long id;
}
```

How can this be achieved when using Hibernate JPA EntityManager?

Maybe by utilising `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean#postProcessEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf, PersistenceUnitInfo pui)`?

I've also found `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl#buildHibernateConfiguration(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)` but I don't know where to "hook in" (I'm using Spring and/or Spring-Boot and Spring-Data).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't  strategy="xyz" supposed to be strategy="com.mycompany.myIdentifierGeneratorClass"?

Comment: strategy must be "...either a predefined Hibernate strategy or a fully qualified class name", see e.g. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html

Comment: In the first code block you identify a class called MyIdentifierGeneratorClass.class; is this your class that you wish to use with JPA annotations (@GenericGenerator(name="", strategy="MyIdentifierGeneratorClass"?

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it in the described "flexible" way. This way MyLocalSessionFactoryBean and BaseEntity can be put in a framework lib on which different projects can depend. But each project can choose its own IdentifierGenerator if myIdentifierGeneratorClass is made configurable e.g. with Springs @Value-Annotation. It's all working with plain Hibernate but up to now I can't establish the same with Hibernate/JPA/EntityManager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a `hibernate.ejb.identifier_generator_strategy_provider` configuration property which defines the fully qualified name of your `IdentifierGeneratorStrategyProvider` implementation.

This `IdentifierGeneratorStrategyProvider` interface defines the following method:

```
public Map<String,Class<?>> getStrategies();
```

which you need to implement and define your own strategy there.

During bootstrap the `EntityManager` will be configured like this:

```
final Object idGeneratorStrategyProviderSetting = configurationValues.remove( AvailableSettings.IDENTIFIER_GENERATOR_STRATEGY_PROVIDER );
if ( idGeneratorStrategyProviderSetting != null ) {
    final IdentifierGeneratorStrategyProvider idGeneratorStrategyProvider =
            strategySelector.resolveStrategy( IdentifierGeneratorStrategyProvider.class, idGeneratorStrategyProviderSetting );
    final MutableIdentifierGeneratorFactory identifierGeneratorFactory = ssr.getService( MutableIdentifierGeneratorFactory.class );
    if ( identifierGeneratorFactory == null ) {
        throw persistenceException(
                "Application requested custom identifier generator strategies, " +
                        "but the MutableIdentifierGeneratorFactory could not be found"
        );
    }
    for ( Map.Entry<String,Class<?>> entry : idGeneratorStrategyProvider.getStrategies().entrySet() ) {
        identifierGeneratorFactory.register( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
}
```

so, the strategy you define will be configured in the `MutableIdentifierGeneratorFactory` just as you were doing previously.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I hoped for your help! ;-)
1. The code snippet looks like from the 5.0.x branch.
2. Since I'm actually using Spring-Boot, I'm using the 4.3.11 version.
3. In 4.3.11 the code looks a little bit different, but if I look at it again (after reading your helpful post) I understand and it looks promising!

Will try it as soon as possible! Thanks!